# Rust recipe depends on library from other recipe

Tags: postgresql, bitbake, meta-raspberrypi

I am trying to generate a package from a Bitbake recipe for Raspberry Pi:

```sh
inherit cargo

SUMMARY = "myapp"
DESCRIPTION = "Compile and configure myapp"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
HOMEPAGE = "git://git.myserver.com:myapp/myapp.git"

DEPENDS = "openssl postgresql"

SRC_URI = "git://git.myserver.com/myapp/myapp.git;protocol=https;user=myuser:mypass;tag=v${PV}"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
```

The program I am compiling depends on the PostgreSQL library **libpq** which is generated by the **postgresql** package. My problem is that the linker cannot find libpq, even been in DEPENDS.

The output error is:

```
...
"-Wl,--end-group" "/home/yocto-image/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/myapp/0.0.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-e2523c360f03ba10.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lpq" "-lgcc_s" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc"
|   = note: /home/yocto-image/build/tmp/hosttools/ld: cannot find -lpq
|           collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
| 
| 
| error: aborting due to previous error
| 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution. I was cross-compiling the code in a Ubuntu x86_64 PC. The library was necessary for the compiling machine not for the target machine (Raspberry Pi). The solution is just to install the libraries needed in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```